# What does 'by the glint of possibility' mean?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

> That’s what makes me cry. I was once a vice-president, a member of the Chairman’s Club. In the past it was always enough to be connected to humanity in a more abstract way, **by the glint of possibility**. To believe that there’s order and I have a place in it, is just too scary, that if I’m not here doing what I’m supposed to do, nothing else will be right.
>   (["There Is a Plan"—Kathy Holwadel](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/15305/))

What does "by the glint of possibility" mean? Does it mean that to be connected to humanity in a more abstract way is not probable?

Comment: This is almost certainly an [eggcorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) for a phrase the author is only vaguely familiar with, "by [dint](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/dint) of". The author means she wants to be connected only *contingently*, because to be *necessarily* connected imposes more responsibility than she is willing to undertake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, a "glint of possibility" means **a brief flash of possibility**. The term glint tends to be used to describe a small amount of something reflective or shiny. For example:

> The sun **glinted** off the coin as I spotted it in the ground.